# TimeStamp for RSS Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, rss, windows-phone-8, timestamp, webclient

I built the entire structure and setup the RSS feed already for my app. But, I can't seem to add a timestamp to the refresh button that automatically updates the date and time the feed replenishes itself. Can someone give me an example that works with the webclient helper class?

Comment: please show us some code / what you've tried since there isn't enough information here to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Last updated:"/>
    <TextBlock Name="Updated"/>
    <Button Tap="OnTap">Update</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Page.xaml.cs (Code-behind)

```
private void OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // Add RSS update logic here
    Updated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Adjusting the UI is really simple. This way isn't how I'd recommend it, because it'd add logic to the View.

Things to keep in mind:

1. You should consider using a ViewModel to set the page's DataContext to. The ViewModel can contain a public property such as LastUpdated, to which you can bind a TextBlock to which can display that property.
2. Consider using commands to separate logic from your View.

I think this answers (part of) your question. If you wish to know more about implementing RSS feeds, you should consider making a seperate question.

Comment: <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,149,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="Updated" Text="Last Update:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> This is how I got it to fit in the overall code, and it built when I added this line to the loadfeed_click event handle. Updated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); Thank You, and if I have any other issues, I'll report back to you